# Pick up the link with (Is the use of "pick up" in this context common?)

Tags: word-usage

> Zylie panicked a little when her computer wouldn't **pick up the link with the projector**, but Mr. Stock simply shrugged it off and said we could present directly from the computer.

I know that "didn't pick up the link" means that "it didn't connect with the projector". Is the use of "pick up" this way common,  because I couldn't find its use this online......  Can it just be:

> Zylie panicked when the computer didn't connect to the projector.
>
> Zylie panicked when the computer didn't link with the projector(Or should it be :"didn't link to the projector"?)

Edited.

Comment: You seem to randomly switch between *computer didn't connect to projector* and *projector didn't connect to computer*. Perhaps it would be better not to point the finger of blame (at her computer, or their projector), and just say ***the connection to the projector didn't work***.

Comment: Oh...  Yeah I just noticed.  I'll edit it.

Comment: So @FumbleFingers dont either of the three sentences (the last one with an option b/w "link to and link with") sound natural?

Comment: The expression ***pick up the link with*** (make a connection between two IT devices) strongly implies a ***wireless*** link (wi-fi, bluetooth,...). Having worked in tech support, I might be inclined to suggest the fault could just as well be in a wireless router, or some problem with network permissions. Which in itself highlights another possible difference between *picking up a link* and *connecting*, in that the latter could be used where the PC *recognises that the device is present* (it just can't *connect to and use it*). Whereas the former can't really carry that sense.

Comment: Whatever - to ***pick up the link*** is somewhat "geeky", and it's obviously [far less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+picks+up+the+link%2Ccomputer+connects&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20connects%3B%2Cc0) than straightforward ***connect***, so I suggest you stick with the latter.

Comment: Is "pick up the link" something you've heard native speakers use?  I won't say it's *wrong*, because it might be a relatively new expression used by younger people, and I'm out of date.

Comment: I can think of very few contexts where *pick up the link to* is idiomatic. Having said that, it wouldn't mean exactly the same thing as either or your rephrased sentences.

Comment: So what would it mean @JasonBassford ?

Comment: As I said, it's unidiomatic, so I may not be able to provide a particular meaning. However, let's say that wireless broadcast towers are constantly sending out *links* to mobile phones that look for them. You could say that your phone *picked up [found] the [a] link*. It's true that if it doesn't, it's not connected on wireless; however, they are two different things. It's not connected *because* it didn't pick up the link. It's the same as saying that your lights are off *because* you couldn't find the light switch.